# Why is $x$ divided by $n$ the same as $1$ divided by $n$ times $x$?

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm very new here and my question must have been answered before, but I don't know how to search this site with problems like mine.

My question is why $x/n$ is the same as $1/n*x$?

Also, if you don't mind, tell me how to search this site effectively with questions like mine. When I type something like this, every imaginable question shows up because of the search of symbols $x$ and $n$ and so on I guess.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: procedurally, division is always the same as multiplying by the reciprocal.

Comment: What do $\frac xn$, $\frac1n$ and ${}\cdot x$ actually, _formally_, mean to you? You can't begin to adress this question before you have the basic definitions sorted out.

Comment: You are clear, are you, that $x/n$ is the same as $(\frac{1}{n})*x$.

Answer (score 1):

Division with fractions is defined to be multiplication by a reciprocal.

For example, $$\frac23 \div \frac 25 = \frac23 \times \frac52 = \frac53.$$

When the divisor doesn't appear to have a denominator, remember it is implicitly $1$:

$$x \div n = \frac{x}1 \div \frac{n}1 = \frac{x}1\times\frac1{n} = \frac{x}{n}.$$

---

**Addendum:** You may wonder why division with fractions is defined in this way.

It can be arrived at by regarding division as a "bigger" fraction:

$$\frac ab \div \frac cd = \frac{\;\frac ab\;}{\frac cd}$$
$$=\frac{\;\frac ab\;}{\frac cd}\times 1$$
$$=\frac{\;\frac ab\;}{\frac cd}\times \frac{\;\frac dc\;}{\frac dc}$$
$$=\frac{\frac ab \times \frac dc}{\frac cd \times \frac dc}$$
$$=\frac{\frac ab \times \frac dc}{1}$$
$$=\frac ab \times \frac dc$$

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to think of it.

Perhaps the most practical is: $\frac xn$ usually means (depending on what context; how abstract; what your philosophy of what mathematics actual *is*; and what type of conversationalist you are at cocktail parties) you have a quantity of $x$ stuff and you are dividing it into $n$ equal pieces how many is each piece.  Well, you have $x$ stuff and each $1$ of those $x$ stuff is split into $n$ pieces so each $1$ is split into $n$ pieces $\frac 1n$ in size each.  And each of the $x$ stuff contriibute on $n$th of itself to the whole thing and you have $x$ of these $\frac 1n$ pieces.  So that is $x\cdot \frac 1n$ of the stuff.

This implies $n$ is a whole number and although $x$ might not be it is somehow measurable in relation to quantities of $1$.

More abstract and mathematical:

Multiplication is a "binary operation" so that given any two real numbers $a$ and $b$ if you "do the operation on them" then $a\cdot b$ will equal some real number always.  You can't have $3\cdot 7=21$ and $2\sqrt 3\cdot \sqrt 6=6\sqrt 2$ but $9\cdot 7$ doesn't equal anything at all, or $5\cdot 1=$ pink elephant.  $a\cdot b$ always equals *some* number.

By axiom for any real number $a\ne 0$ there is a real number $a^{-1}$ called the multiplicative inverse, which has the property that $a\cdot a^{-1} =1$.  For notation and notation only we write this number as $\frac 1a$.  $\frac 1a$ is a real numbers so $x\cdot \frac 1n$ must equal some number.  For notation purposes we write $x\cdot \frac 1n$ as $\frac xn$.  It *means* the number: $x$ multiplied by the number that when multiplied by $n$ would give you $1$.

That is the *definition* there is no such thing as "division". The concept of $x\div n = \frac xn$ will mean in the  context of Abstract Algebra way of thinking:  Take the number $x$ and perform the "multiplication" operation on it with that number than if you did the operation with $n$ would give you $1$.

.....

So those are two very different but valid ways of thinking of what math *is*.

1) is practical:  Look, take some pizzas and cut them into slices.  Look it has to work because splitting a bunch of pizzas won't change just because of the order you do it in. (So just do it, kid.  That's how the world works.)

2) is abstract and axiomatic:  Mathematics is a game of definitions and axioms and rules.  This is so because we chose to define the axioms so that it is so.  (Now shut up and eat your soup.)

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{x}{n}$ defines $x$ pieces of size $\dfrac{1}{n}$, the way you would call $\dfrac{3}{4}$ of an orange three quarters of an orange, or how a mark of $\dfrac{43}{50}$ in a test is 43 points worth, because one mark is defined as $\dfrac{1}{50}$ of the possible 50 marks available.